# Flume use of multiplexing channel selector

Tags: flume, multiplexing

I am trying to implement flume to ingest the data around 1TB. For this I am trying to use the multiplexing channel selector.

There are some examples available that shows how to use the multiplexing channel selector.

**My question is how one can determine the header content of an event?**

For example, in below configuration, I am using multiplexing channel selector with header as State and mapping is made to CN, ID, IN etc.

```
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.type = multiplexing
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.header = State
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.mapping.CN = channel1
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.mapping.IN = channel2
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.mapping.ID = channel2
spoolDirAgent.sources.source1.selector.defalut = channel1
```

Also if possible, please let me know how to use the event headers in flume sources?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, please let me know how we can check whether the event header contains the header value as State?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the flume-ng user guide indicated, if the event header doesn't contain key 'State', then the default
channel will be used. and search "static interceptor" in flume-ng user guide, then more or less you'll know how to add key 'State' into the header.

Comment: I think the Regex Extractor Interceptor is more suited than the Static one. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287766/how-to-use-regex-extractor-selector-and-multiplexing-interceptor-together-in-flu