# How to use regex_extractor selector and multiplexing interceptor together in flume?

Tags: selector, interceptor, flume

I am testing flume to load data into hHase and thinking about parallel data loading with using flume's selector and inteceptor, because of speed gap between source and sink.

So, what I want to do with flume are

1. creating Event's header with interceptors's regex_extractor type
2. multiplexing Event with header to more than two channels with selector's multiplexing type

   in one source-channel-sink.

and tried configuration as below.

```
    agent.sources = tailsrc
    agent.channels = mem1 mem2
    agent.sinks = std1 std2
    agent.sources.tailsrc.type = exec
    agent.sources.tailsrc.command = tail -F /home/flumeuser/test/in.txt
    agent.sources.tailsrc.batchSize = 1
    
    agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors = i1
    agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.type = regex_extractor
    agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.regex = ^(\\d)
    agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.serializers = t1
    agent.sources.tailsrc.interceptors.i1.serializers.t1.name = type
    
    agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.type = multiplexing
    agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.header = type
    agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.1 = mem1
    agent.sources.tailsrc.selector.mapping.2 = mem2
    
    agent.sinks.std1.type = file_roll
    agent.sinks.std1.channel = mem1
    agent.sinks.std1.batchSize = 1
    agent.sinks.std1.sink.directory = /var/log/flumeout/1
    agent.sinks.std1.rollInterval = 0
    
    agent.sinks.std2.type = file_roll
    agent.sinks.std2.channel = mem2
    agent.sinks.std2.batchSize = 1
    agent.sinks.std2.sink.directory = /var/log/flumeout/2
    agent.sinks.std2.rollInterval = 0
    
    agent.channels.mem1.type = memory
    agent.channels.mem1.capacity = 100
    
    agent.channels.mem2.type = memory
    agent.channels.mem2.capacity = 100
```

But, it doesn't work!

when selector part is removed, there are some interceptor debugging message in flume's log.
but when selector and interceptor are together, there are nothing.

Is there any wrong expression or something I missed?

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 1):

I found it.

In the flume log, there are warning message as below.

```
    2013-10-10 16:34:20,514 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSources(FlumeConfiguration.java:571)] Removed tailsrc due to Failed to configure component!
```

so I had attached below line

```
    agent.sources.tailsrc.channels = mem1 mem2
```

and then It works!!!!

Comment: This is binding source and chanel. Also need to bind sink and chanel by `agent.sinks.std1 = mem1` and `agent.sinks.std2 = mem2`