# writing csv file on hdfs but before writing on hdfs how to filter csv file using flume static interceptor

Tags: csv, flume

I used below configuration for filtering my `csv` file but it is unable to filter.

I used `static interceptor` for filtering, do I need to use any other interceptor? Please suggest me what I need to write in below config file.

My csv file sample below.

```
Id,Name,First,Last,Display,Job,Department,OfficeNo,OfficePh,MobilePh,Fax,Address,City,State,ZIP,Country 
1,chris@contoso.com,Chris,Green,Chris Green,IT Manager,Information Technology,123451,123-555-1211,123-555-6641,9821,1 Microsoft way,Redmond,Wa,98052,United States
2,ben@contoso.com,Ben,Andrews,Ben Andrews,IT Manager,Information Technology,123452,123-555-1212,123-555-6642,9822,1 Microsoft way,Redmond,Wa,98052,United States
3,david@contoso.com,David,Longmuir,David Longmuir,IT Manager,Information Technology,123453,123-555-1213,123-555-6643,9823,1 Microsoft way,Redmond,Wa,98052,United States
4,cynthia@contoso.com,Cynthia,Carey,Cynthia Carey,IT Manager,Information Technology,123454,123-555-1214,123-555-6644,9824,1 Microsoft way,Redmond,Wa,98052,United States
```

my `flume-conf.properties` file is listed below, and I am expecting output like `(Id=1)` go through `ch1` and `(Id=2)` go through `ch2` and other `Id(3,4)` go through `default` channel.

Please help me out doing it.

```
a1.sources=src1 
a1.channels=ch1 ch2    
a1.sinks=s1 s2    

a1.sources.src1.type=exec
a1.sources.src1.command=tail -F /home/manish/TwitterExample  /Import_User_Sample_en.csv

a1.channels.ch1.type=memory
a1.channels.ch1.capacity=10000
a1.channels.ch1.transactioncapacity=100

a1.channels.ch2.type = memory
a1.channels.ch2.capacity = 10000
a1.channels.ch2.transactioncapacity = 100
```

Static interceptor as follows

```
a1.sources.src1.interceptors=i1 
a1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.type=static
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i1.key=Id
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i1.value=1
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i1.preserveExisting=false

a1.sources.src1.interceptor=i2
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i2.type=static
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i2.key=Id
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i2.value=2
a1.sources.src1.interceptor.i2.preserveExisting=false

a1.sources.src1.fileHeader=true
a1.sources.src1.selector.type=multiplexing
a1.sources.src1.selector.header=Id
a1.sources.src1.selector.mapping.1=ch1
a1.sources.src1.selector.mapping.2 =ch2
a1.sources.src1.selector.default = ch2

a1.sinks.s1.type=hdfs 
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.path=hdfs://kdp.ambarikdp1.com:8020/user/data/twitter
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.filetype=DataStream
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.rollCount=0
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.rollSize=0
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.rollInterval=300
a1.sinks.s1.hdfs.serializer=HEADER_AND_TEXT


a1.sinks.s2.type = hdfs
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.path = hdfs://kdp.ambarikdp1.com:8020/user/data/t2
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.filetype = DataStream
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.rollCount = 0
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.rollSize = 0
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.rollInterval = 300
a1.sinks.s2.hdfs.serializer=HEADER_AND_TEXT

a1.sources.src1.channels=ch1 ch2  
a1.sinks.s1.channel=ch1
a1.sinks.s2.channel = ch2
```

Answer (score 0):

At least, the way you are using multiple interceptors is wrong. Interceptors must be added as a list this way:

```
a1.sources.src1.interceptors = i1 i2
```

Then, you can configure each one of them:

```
a1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.type = ...
a1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.other = ...
...
a1.sources.src1.interceptors.i2.type = ...
a1.sources.src1.interceptors.i2.other = ...
...
```

Being said that, I think the static interceptor is not what you need, since AFAIK it always adds the same static header to all the events. I mean, all the events will have the same header name and value, independently of the "id" field.

Please, have a look on [How to use regex_extractor selector and multiplexing interceptor together in flume?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287766/how-to-use-regex-extractor-selector-and-multiplexing-interceptor-together-in-flu), i.e. using the [Regex Extractor Interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-extractor-interceptor) instead.

Comment: Yes sir you are right same thing i got .but my expectaion is like event in which Id "1"  is present that whole event stored in one file and the event in which Id "2" present that whole event stored in another file. so how will regular expression work for that.

but when i used regex_extractor interceptor and serializers in my config then it give me error like "IllegalArgumentException: Must supply at least one name and serializer" what is reason for that and what will be the name of serializer in my case i used "Id" as serializer name and try to mapping value base on that id value

Comment: There is an example about how to configure the serializer names (the type, if not specified none, is the default one) at https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#regex-extractor-interceptor